# Can chemical vapor deposition chambers be used to lay down thick layers of metal?

Tags: chemical-engineering, metals, experimental-physics

Can CVD Chambers be used to lay down thick (~1 mm) layers of metal?

Answer (score 2):

you do not need a CVD system to deposit metals, a planar magnetron sputtering system is more suitable. But for layers of order ~1mm in thickness you would be better off with an electroplating process.